# Approximation of a times series with a given function in matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series, approximation, function-fitting

I am trying to fit in matlab a temperature time series that follows this kind of function[image]

I would need to retrieve the 8 parameters of the function, putting as boundary lambda=0 and sigma positive.
I tried using the lsqcurvefit function in matlab, but I cannot use the y function inside this built in matlab funtion if I have a for loop in place.

```
Torontoless=xlsread('temp.xlsx',2);
xdata=zeros(1,6576);
x=[0,0,0,0,0,0];
ydata=Torontoless';
Toronto=[zeros(size(ydata,1),1) ydata];
fun=zeros(1,6576);
for i=1:6576
fun(i)=(1-x(1))*(Toronto(i)-(x(2)+x(3)*Toronto(i)+x(4)*(sin(x(5)*Toronto(i)+x(6)))))+x(2)+x(3)*Toronto(i+1)+x(4)*(sin(x(5)*Toronto(i+1)+x(6)))+(randn-x(7))*x(8);
end

x0=[0,0,0,0,0,0];
lb=[-1000,-1000,-1000,-1000,-1000,-1000,0,0];
ub=[1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,0,1000];
```

Now, I don't know how to use the fun inside the function `x=lsqcurvefit(fun,x0,xdata,ydata,lb,ub)`

I don't know if there is a better way to fit this kind of time series, but let me know if you have something in mind to solve the problem.
Thanks a lot.

PS The size of the temp vector is 1x6576. As I wanted temperature to start at 0, I added an extra column at first.

Comment: The problem looks a bit weird to me, the new temperature depends on the temperature on the previous time step? `j` is a discrete time variable? Could you explain a bit more about your data?

Comment: yes, sorry that j-1 and j in the second line of the figure is a T_{j-1} and T_{j}, so the temperature today depend on yesterday too.

Comment: I see only 5 parameters. *(&epsilon; &lambda;).&sigma;* is some noise term. You need to express the measured temperatures *T_j* as a function of &alpha; and model temperatures *Tm_j* and *Tm_(j-1)*. *C.sin(&omega;j+&Phi;)* can be expressed as *D.sin(&omega;j)+E.cos(&omega;j)*. For a given &alpha;, seeking a best fit for A,B,D&E is a simple linear optimization problem. Then seeking the value of &alpha; that gives the best fit is a 1D optimization problem.